# Make a form to pass parameters

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've a form but it doesn't pass the parameters 'url' and 'USERNAME' to the next page. Is there something wrong?

I must use `<button>` instead of `<input>` for styling issues.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/confirmation/index.php" method="post" class="form-wrap">
<div class="loader-wrap">
<div class="loader-txt">
</div>
</div>

<div class="field-set url-field">
<input type="text" name="url" data-placeholder="Your Website URL" maxlength="50" class="validate">. 
<button name="url_btn" type="button" class="btn url-btn">Scan My Site!</button>
</div>

<div class="field-set email-field">
<input type="text" name="USERNAME" data-placeholder="Your E-mail" maxlength="50" class="validate">
<button name="email_btn" type="button" class="btn email-btn" style="width:174px;font-size:15px;">Send me Results!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: is ur form open tag ( <form> ) missing ?

Comment: Do you have a opening form tag ? Or did you just forget to copy it?

Comment: It was there, just the answer wasn't properly formatted so the editor "ate" the opening tag.

Comment: The values seem to be passed correctly, how are you accessing them on the next page?

Comment: I think you have forgot the submit button which submits the form! Like this: <input type="submit" value="Send Form!">

Answer (score 5):

email_btn should be of type="submit" instead of type="button", so rather:

```
<button type="submit">Send me the results</button>
```

see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Answer (score -1):

This should work with a submit Button!

(The extra php is to show that it works!)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    echo "form submitted";
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" class="form-wrap">
    <div class="loader-wrap">
        <div class="loader-txt">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field-set url-field">
        <input type="text" name="url" data-placeholder="Your Website URL" maxlength="50" class="validate">. 
        <button name="url_btn" type="button" class="btn url-btn">Scan My Site!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="field-set email-field">
        <input type="text" name="USERNAME" data-placeholder="Your E-mail" maxlength="50" class="validate">
        <button name="email_btn" type="button" class="btn email-btn" style="width:174px;font-size:15px;">Send me Results!</button>
        <button name="submitted" type="submit">Send me the results</button> //Submit Button 
    </div>
</form>
```